# Is there a way to add asp.net MVC 5 web project with Bootstrap template inside Visual Studio 2012

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I have visual studio 2012 and I have installed the latest update for it from, to get all the asp.net mvc 5 templetes:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696518/Using-ASP-NET-MVC-within-Visual-Studio

But currently i only have an option to create a new asp.net MVC 5 empty project, but I am trying to create a new project which uses the bootstrap template.

So is this possible, and how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nuget package for MVC4 that contains simple template for twitter bootstrap. But I haven't found the same for MVC5, so I guess, you can add twitter bootstrap only manually

Comment: but on some online tutorials and samples they use bootstrap templete on asp.net mvc 5 ..

Comment: Are they creating a new project with preinstalled template, or just show ready project with installed template?

Comment: the bootstrap is the default templete when creating asp.net mvc web application insdie VS2013, so you do not have to specify the template ..unless you create an asp.net mvc5 empty project..

Comment: so, I guess, it can help you http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5ed81082-fc81-458a-a30c-0d15b6e8386f